# post request by axios to laravel giving 500 error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am using Laravel with Vue making http request with the axios. It is giving 500 error. 
My request code is

```
axios.post('user', {
       first_name: this.user.first_name,
       last_name: this.user.last_name,
       email: this.user.email,
       phone_number: this.user.phone_number,
       is_active: this.user.is_active,
       entity: this.user.entity,
       role_id: this.user.role_id
     })
```

Lavael Route is

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

And Controller is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
      'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
      'email' => 'required',
      'is_active' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
      'first_name' => request('first_name'),
      'last_name' => request('last_name'),
      'email' => request('email'),
      'is_active' => request('is_active'),
      'phone_number' => request('phone_number'),
      'role_id' => request('role_id')
    ]);

    return response()->json([
      'user' => $user,
      'message' => 'Success'
    ], 200);

}
```

Comment: Can you try `/user`?
If this does not work please recheck whether the full path is `/user` ?

Comment: Could you please provide the error.

Comment: Provide the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your store method is correct. You just need to specify the correct path to your axios post request, which means your component method should be like this :

```
axios.post('/user/store', {
       first_name: this.user.first_name,
       last_name: this.user.last_name,
       email: this.user.email,
       phone_number: this.user.phone_number,
       is_active: this.user.is_active,
       entity: this.user.entity,
       role_id: this.user.role_id
     }).then((res) => {
          // here clear your form and fetch your users list if you want 
     })
       .catch(error => {
          // here catch error messages from laravel validator and show them 
     });
```

and your store method should return validator messages error :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
             'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
             'email' => 'required',
             'is_active' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()],422);
    }

    $user = User::create([
      'first_name' => $request('first_name'),
      'last_name' => $request('last_name'),
      'email' => $request('email'),
      'is_active' => $request('is_active'),
      'phone_number' => $request('phone_number'),
      'role_id' => $request('role_id')
    ]);

    return response()->json([
      'user' => $user,
      'message' => 'Success'
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
axios.post('/user/store', {
    first_name: this.user.first_name,
    last_name: this.user.last_name,
    email: this.user.email,
    phone_number: this.user.phone_number,
    is_active: this.user.is_active,
    entity: this.user.entity,
    role_id: this.user.role_id
  })
  .then(response => { 
    console.log(response)
 })
 .catch(error => {
   console.log(error.response)
 });
```

Try this code instead & always console.log your error with **error.response** to get all info & objects with full error details. Check in chrome console that all your POST datas from form are passed correctly to your database. In my case i figured out that my phone field where not passed due to typo mistake.
[My console error Image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYw7z.png)

or you can try 2nd method below for laravel users :-

1. `composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors`
2. Add the Cors\ServiceProvider to your config/app.php provider’s array `Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,`
3. To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the $middleware property of app/Http/Kernel.php `protected $middleware = [
                                      \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
                            ];`
4. php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider" `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"`

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the following code block:

```
$user = User::create([
  'first_name' => request('first_name'),
  'last_name' => request('last_name'),
  'email' => request('email'),
  'is_active' => request('is_active'),
  'phone_number' => request('phone_number'),
  'role_id' => request('role_id')
]);
```

Replace with below:

```
$user = User::create([
  'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
  'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
  'email' => $request->input('email'),
  'is_active' => $request->input('is_active'),
  'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
  'role_id' => $request->input('role_id')
]);
```

Comment: `request->input` should be `$request->input`, right?

Comment: @kerbholz yes you are right i have corrected my suggestion. Thanks for that!

Comment: Not working.  Giving following error

 POST http://localhost/lms-dev/public/user 500 (Internal Server Error)
 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:19978)
    at settle (app.js:47695)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:19852)

Comment: @HasanRaza are you using some frontend framework like angular or else.

Comment: @amitrawat I'm using Vue.js.

Comment: @HasanRaza Please could provide app.js code where you get error.

Comment: @amitrawat
axios.post('user', {
           first_name: this.user.first_name,
           last_name: this.user.last_name,
           email: this.user.email,
           phone_number: this.user.phone_number,
           is_active: this.user.is_active,
           entity: this.user.entity,
           role_id: this.user.role_id
         }).then(res => {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
           this.$refs.modal_create_user.hide();
         }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
         });